# PNG not an option on GLTF export

Tags: export, transparency, gltf

There's no PNG format option on GLTF export, it simply doesn't exist. I require this function to export a transparent material. Here are things I've tried

1. Blender 2.83.13 and 2.90.1
2. Eevee and Cycles renderer
3. Using Principled BSDF for color and alpha in the node editor
4. setting blend mode to Alpha Blend in material properties
5. changing the texture interpolation in node editor
6. yelling *a lot*

[image: no png option]

[image]

Comment: this is absolutely NOT a feature request, its a feature that can clearly be seen used in this blender video https://youtu.be/p7OPRoT6FkY?t=100

Comment: Both "Automatic" and "JPEG" should export a PNG for any image that needs transparency. Maybe show your material nodes.

Comment: Ok. That exports fine and imports back in with transparency when I try it. What exactly happens for you?

Comment: Thanks for the idea of importing back to blender! Somewhere along the way my original export had turned into an emission shader. It's frustrating to try to follow along with someone and they have features in the software and you don't, especially ones that clearly look to solve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm the one who removed the "PNG" option btw. It did the same thing as "Automatic", except it also converted JPEGs to PNGs. Since that's totally useless and only makes the file bigger, it was kind of trap (as seen in the linked video).